# How can I prevent table columns from wrapping when the browser is re-sized?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table structure of 10 rows. The problem is that the columns content get wrapped when I reduce browser page size. It looks awkward when I re-sized page to half of its original size.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<table class="emailsTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr class="gridHeaderBar">
        <th colspan="8" class="TableFirstRow">
            <span class="LeftAlign">Emails </span>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" class="txtSearch" value="Search Attachments"
                            onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search Attachments') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search Attachments';}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch" value="" onclick="Search()"
                            title="Search Attachment(s)" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/refresh16.gif" alt="Refresh" onclick="Refresh()"
                                class="refresh" title="Refresh" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridColumnHeaderBar">
        <td style="width: 1%;">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/ico_16_5001.gif" alt="Activity Type" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 1%;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="Content/themes/base/images/ico_16_attach.gif" alt="E-Mail Attachment(s)"
                            style="margin-left: 2px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 11%;" class="ColHover" onclick="SortbyTo()">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                To</label>
            <div id="to_sort_direction" class="sortUp">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 11%;">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                From</label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 12%;" class="ColHover" onclick="SortbySubject()">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                Subject</label>
            <div id="subject_sort_direction" class="sortUp">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 15%;" class="ColHover" onclick="SortbyDescription()">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                Description</label>
            <div id="description_sort_direction" class="sortUp">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                Created on</label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 6%;">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                Attachment(s)</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1" class="row" onclick="DisplayEmailDetails(this)">
        <td>
            <img id="row1_type" style="display: none;" src="Content/themes/base/images/ico_16_4202.gif"
                alt="Activity Type" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr id="row1_attachmentcol">
                    <td style="border: 0px;">
                        <img id="row1_attachment" style="display: none; margin-left: 7px;" src="Content/themes/base/images/ico_16_attach.gif"
                            alt="E-Mail Attachment(s)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_to" class="divLabel">
            </label>
            <input type="hidden" id="row1_id" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_from" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_subject" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_description" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_createdon" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_attachmentcount" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    ...

    </table>
   </body>
```

Following is the CSS (selective):

```
html
{
font-family: "segoe ui";
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-size: .75em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
.emailsTable
{
width: 100%;
}
.gridHeaderBar
{
background-color: #EFF2F6;
height: 26px;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 2px;
}
.TableFirstRow
{
border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
border-top: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
.LeftAlign
{
color: #3b3b3b;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
height: 24px;
margin-top: 2px;
padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
}
.gridColumnHeaderBar
{
height: 22px;
border-top: 1px solid #a5acb5;
border-bottom: 1px solid #a5acb5;
border-left: 1px solid #a5acb5;
border-right: 1px solid #a5acb5;
background-image: url('themes/base/images/GridColumnGradient_White.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
border-spacing:0;
}
.ColHover:hover
{
background-image: url('themes/base/images/GridColumnGradientHover_White.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height:20px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.row
{
font-size: 12px;
background-color: White;
}

.row td
{
border-bottom:1pt solid #CFD4DA;
height: 20px;
margin-left: 2px;
}

.row:hover
{
background-color: #CEE3F6 !important;
}
```

As my above code shows that I am using percentages in defining width of elements. Any valuable suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please enclose your `table` within a `div` having a specific `min-width`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dDN77/)

```
<body>
<div class="tab">
<table class="emailsTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr class="gridHeaderBar">
        <th colspan="8" class="TableFirstRow">
            <span class="LeftAlign">Emails </span>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" class="txtSearch" value="Search Attachments"
                            onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search Attachments') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search Attachments';}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch" value="" onclick="Search()"
                            title="Search Attachment(s)" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/refresh16.gif" alt="Refresh" onclick="Refresh()"
                                class="refresh" title="Refresh" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridColumnHeaderBar">
        <td style="width: 1%;">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/ico_16_5001.gif" alt="Activity Type" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 1%;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="Content/themes/base/images/ico_16_attach.gif" alt="E-Mail Attachment(s)"
                            style="margin-left: 2px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 11%;" class="ColHover" onclick="SortbyTo()">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                To</label>
            <div id="to_sort_direction" class="sortUp">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 11%;">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                From</label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 12%;" class="ColHover" onclick="SortbySubject()">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                Subject</label>
            <div id="subject_sort_direction" class="sortUp">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 15%;" class="ColHover" onclick="SortbyDescription()">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                Description</label>
            <div id="description_sort_direction" class="sortUp">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                Created on</label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 6%;">
            <img src="Content/themes/base/images/GridColumnVerticalLine_White.png" style="margin-left: 2px;" />
            <label style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                Attachment(s)</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1" class="row" onclick="DisplayEmailDetails(this)">
        <td>
            <img id="row1_type" style="display: none;" src="Content/themes/base/images/ico_16_4202.gif"
                alt="Activity Type" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr id="row1_attachmentcol">
                    <td style="border: 0px;">
                        <img id="row1_attachment" style="display: none; margin-left: 7px;" src="Content/themes/base/images/ico_16_attach.gif"
                            alt="E-Mail Attachment(s)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_to" class="divLabel">
            </label>
            <input type="hidden" id="row1_id" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_from" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_subject" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_description" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_createdon" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="row1_attachmentcount" class="divLabel">
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    ...

    </table>
    </div>
   </body>
```

Add this to your css

```
.tab{
    min-width: 500px;
}
```